# Matplotlib: change font of datetime axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I change the font of a datetime x-axis in Matplotlib?

The `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))` from other answers only allows to change the date format, not the text formatting (font family, type, etc.), and `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), **font_prop)` also doesn't work because `ax.get_xticklabels()` returns numbers instead of datetime objects and I have failed to convert them back to dates.

Comment: I don’t think either of the linked answers answer the original question.

Comment: I agree. It looks like the moderator didn't carefully read my question...